# How to invalidate react-query whenever state is changed?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I'm trying to refetch my user data with react-query whenever a certain state is changed. But ofcourse I can't use a hook within a hook so i can't figure out how to set a dependency on this state.

Current code to fetch user is:

```
const {data: userData, error: userError, status: userStatus} = useQuery(['user', wallet], context => getUserByWallet(context.queryKey[1]));
```

This works fine. But I need this to be invalidated whenever the gobal state wallet is changed. Figured I could make something like

```
useEffect(
    () => {
        useQueryClient().invalidateQueries(
            { queryKey: ['user'] }
        )
    },
    [wallet]
)
```

but this doesn't work because `useQueryClient` is a hook and can't be called within a callback.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

General idea is wallet can change in the app at any time which can be connected to a different user. So whenever wallet state is changed this user needs to be fetched.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useQueryClient` returns object, which you can use later.

For example:

```
const queryClient = useQueryClient()

useEffect(
    () => {
        queryClient.invalidateQueries(
            { queryKey: ['user'] }
        )
    },
    [wallet]
)
```

Comment: Huh makes sense actually! Noticed the `refetchQueries` is in that obj with autocomplete which probably makes more sense too. Thank you, will accept when i can! :)

Comment: You might want to invalidate the query in ‘onSuccess’ instead of using the ‘useEffect’ hook.

Comment: @c0m1t I agree, if wallet is fetched using react-query that's best way. If not (OP is mentioning global state) thats not possible.

Comment: @c0m1t it is indeed not fetched using react-query! Appreciate the comment tho, will look into onSucces since i havent heard of it. New to React. Thanks